# Robust T value in Lavaan R

Tags: r, r-lavaan

Is there any way to get robust *t*-value for the factors in `lavaan` when using confirmatory factor analysis with the function `cfa()` and structural equation modeling with function `sem()`?

Is it the same as the *z*-score when using `summary(fit, fit.measures=TRUE)`?

## Edit:

This is the code I've been using and some results:
[image: Model in R]

How do I get the robust *t*-values from this function?

Comment: Can you add to your question the relevant portion of your code, and perhaps a sample of your data?

Comment: I've added the image of the code used for the model using library Lavaan